# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 150000 y sizes: 50000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Hi I have using this code and getting error

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 150000y sizes: 50000
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

I tried changing the reshape option and even numpy.transpose but no use can anyone help?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

#x_train.shape #(50000, 32, 32, 3) 
#x_test.shape  #(10000, 32, 32, 3)


x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 32, 32 ,1)


x_train = x_train.astype('float32')         # change integers to 32-bit floating point numbers 
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255.0              
x_test /= 255.0


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential() 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)) 
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.build(input_shape=(512,32,32,1)) 
model.summary() 

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1000, epochs=1) 




score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) 
print('Test loss:', score[0]) 
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])


predictions = model.predict([x_test])
#print(predictions)

print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))

img_path = x_test[0]
print(img_path.shape)
if(len(img_path.shape) == 3):
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_path))
elif(len(img_path.shape) == 2):
plt.imshow(img_path)
else:
print("Higher dimensional data")
```

Comment: Plase add the full traceback, not just part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some changes you would have to make. I will write an example for you

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')         
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255.0              
x_test /= 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential() 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)) 

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.summary() 

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```

Changes:

1. you don't need to reshape x_train, x_test as they are already in correct shape.
2. It is always good to use `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` instead of building the model later.
3. I haven't made that change but whenever possible you should use `tf.keras.Sequential` to make models. (more readable, less prone to error). `Functional api` (or your current method) is for when you need to make some complex architecture.
4. You can now increase the model (more layers). I used a few just to show you an example.
5. The `input_shape` in the `InputLayer` is considered as `(batch_size, img_width, img_height, img_channels)` as the `batch_size` could be non-uniform and hence taken as `None` by default so we don't give it and hence we only pass `(img_width, img_height, img_channels)` and as your input has `32 imgwith 32 imgheight and 3 channels` we pass it `(32, 32, 3)`.

If it solved your issue then kindly upvote or give a green tick.